# Can I trigger an automated report that fires once email sent? (Marketing Cloud)

Tags: trigger, marketing-cloud, custom-report-type

Within Marketing Cloud, Is it possible to set up a trigger that once an email has been sent, a report will automatically be generated and sent to an email address 3-5 days after? (to a specific template).

I know some reports can be automated (form the catalog) but it does require manually intervention to set this up.

Comment: Seconded - there doesn't seem to be an answer to such an obvious question.

Comment: This is not an answer, but may be a direction to look into.  Check the REST API library for interactions and see if you can programatically create and run reports through this.  I believe only the REST API has this capability, for some reason they did not give it in SOAP or XML.

Comment: Can you update your question with a rough report layout?

Comment: @AdamSpriggs - just the default one you get in the email send tracking menu.